# Corresponding replacement of different types in python

Tags: python

I'm reading from some files where there are some strings and numbers to replace. I have two tuples `checkItem:` `("x", "y", z)` (where z is an integer) and `repItem:` `(to_replace_x, to_replace_y, to_replace_z)`. `to_replace_x` and `to_replace_y` are string variables while `to_replace_z` is an integer variable.

Currently, this is the code I have to replace the items in a corresponding fashion:

```
for check, rep in zip(checkItem, repItem):
    line = line.replace(check, rep)
```

However, this doesn't work because .replace only works for strings. Is there any way to replace for both strings and integers?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what checkItem and repItem actually look like

Comment: Hi @picobit, checkItem is the tuple ("x", "y" and z) while repItem is the tuple (to_replace_x, to_replace_y, to_replace_z)

Comment: `line.replace(str(check), str(rep))`. `str` is basically a no-op if the argument is already a `str` value.